# Sitecore 9.3 Installation Error without using SIA

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

I am trying to install sitecore without using SIA due some proxy and firewall security issues.I am following steps mentioned in below URL.

https://naveed-ahmad.com/2019/11/28/install-sitecore-9-3-using-3-simple-commands/
But I kept getting below error even if i have changed my SQL Server name and password for sa user in XP0-SingleDeveloper file.

Don't know why it is still trying to connect to localhost server.
[---------------------------------- XConnectXP0_InstallWDP : WebDeploy -----------------------------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
msdeploy.exe : Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.3.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31
char:13

- ```
          & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
  ```
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD:String) [], RemoteException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

More Information: Could not deploy package.
Unable to connect to target server 'localhost'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name,
login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.
Login failed for user 'sa'.
Lear
n more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.

Error: Could not deploy package.

Error: Unable to connect to target server **'localhost'**. Please verify the connection information such as the server
name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.

Error: Login failed for user 'sa'.

Error count: 1.

Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero
exit code - (-1)
At
1.1.1-r4)\XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1:77 char:1

- Install-SitecoreConfiguration @singleDeveloperParams *>&1 | Tee-Objec ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
  ```

[TIME] 00:01:31

Can someone please guide if we need to update any other file for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the **$SqlServer** variable in the ***XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1*** ?
It is possible that *localhost* value comes from the default value which is defined **XP0-SingleDeveloper.json** parameter file and your custom value is not passed to the install script. You may can try to modify the default in the json file directly too.

```
"SQLServer": {
        "Type": "String",
        "DefaultValue": "Localhost",
        "Description": "The Sql Server where databases will be installed."
    }
```